# Type cast / make genric viewModel to be passed as parameter

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I am working on a custom dialog fragment, that is being used/ called from two different views having different `viewModels`. Instead of passing two separate `viewModels` in the constructor parameter of Dialog class as,

```
class CustomeDialog(var viewModel1: ViewModelA ?= null, var viewModel2 : ViewModelB ?= null) : DialogFragment()
```

I need to ask/ figure out a way where I could just set < T> kind of parameter to dialog so I could just type caste any `viewModel` to it, I want.

something like this,

```
class CustomDialog<T:ViewModel> : DialogFragment()
```

and in code, it would be something like

```
val mdialog1: CustomeDialog by lazy { CustomeDialog(viewModel as ViewModelA) }
```

and also

```
 val mdialog2: CustomeDialog by lazy { CustomeDialog(viewMode2 as ViewModelB) }
```

Comment: You should not store Fragment references in lazy properties. If there is a configuration change, the Fragment will be recreated by the OS, and when your property is accessed again, it will create some other instance of the Fragment, so you will have a reference to the one that is *not* on the screen. If you need to access an existing Fragment, find it through the fragment manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a secondary constructor in the generic class that takes in a generic `ViewModel` parameter:

```
class CustomeDialog<T : ViewModel>() : DialogFragment() {
    constructor(viewmodel: T) : this()
}
```

And the usage the same as you did:

```
lateinit var viewModel: ViewModel
val mdialog1: CustomeDialog<ViewModelA> by lazy { CustomeDialog(viewModel as ViewModelA) }
lateinit var viewModel2: ViewModelA
val mdialog2: CustomeDialog<ViewModelA> by lazy { CustomeDialog(viewModel2) }
```

**UPDATE:**

> how to initialize viewModel in dialog based on the type. eg. if VM1 is passed in constructor, then var dialogViewModel = WHAT??,

It's requested to have a Dialog with a generic `ViewModel`, so its type is Generic as it's unknown till it's instantiated.

> yeah i need a local var dialogViewModel which is generic, as i mentioned, whole logic is dependent on this dvm

You can initialize it in the secondary constructor:

```
class CustomDialog<T : ViewModel>() : DialogFragment() {

    lateinit var dialogViewModel: T

    constructor(viewmodel: T) : this() {
        dialogViewModel = viewmodel
    }
}
```

Comment: okay, so now, how to intialize viewModel in dialog based on the type. eg. if VM1 is passed in constructor, then var dialogViewModel = WHAT??, because the whole logic is based on dialogViewModel

Comment: @ZainabZafar Isn't the `GlCodeSearchDialog` has a generic ViewModel type, so why you need to initialize it based on a certain type type? .. Or do you want to have a local `dialogViewModel` var that is generic? This is not clear on the OP

Comment: yeah i need a local var dialogViewModel which is generic, as i mentioned, whole logic is dependent on this dvm, so i just need to initalize it based on the viewModel type i'm passing in constructor, so my whole logic remains same and only dialogViewModel gets the reference of required viewModel that is being passed

Comment: @ZainabZafar Please have a look in the updated answer

Comment: This won't work because the OS won't use the secondary constructor when it recreates the fragment after a configuration change.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks so much I'll have a look at your approach

Comment: @Zain thankyou for your time, i'm happy my mind was signalling me the same answer, but i needed to confirm/ verify it

Answer (score 0):

This strategy cannot work. The OS recreates your Fragment using reflection and its empty constructor. It can restore state to the replacement Fragment using Bundle values, but class types are not a valid type of data for a Bundle.

Closest I can come up with is to make it an abstract class, and then create simple subclasses that have concrete types.

```
abstract class CustomDialog<T: ViewModel>(viewModelType: KClass<out T>): DialogFragment() {
    val viewModel: T by createViewModelLazy(viewModelType, { viewModelStore })
}

class CustomDialogA: CustomDialog<ViewModelA>(ViewModelA::class)
class CustomDialogB: CustomDialog<ViewModelB>(ViewModelB::class)
```